# dynamic expression to method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I can't get it work

```
@grid.GetHtml(
   tableStyle: "bordertable",
   columns: grid.Columns(

       grid.Column("aaaa", format: @<text> @Roles.GetRolesForUser(@item.UserName).LastOrDefault() </text>  ),
       grid.Column("UserName", "bbbb"),
       grid.Column("FirstName", "cccc"),
       grid.Column("LastName", "dddd")
     ))
```

the problem is with

```
@Roles.GetRolesForUser().LastOrDefault(@item.UserName)
```

without `@item.UserName` it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
@Roles.GetRolesForUser(item.UserName).LastOrDefault()
```

not

```
@Roles.GetRolesForUser().LastOrDefault(item.UserName)
```

also since @ is already defined with @Roles you do not have to use @ again (@Item.UserName)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It works without `(@item.UserName)` because if you don't precise a source `LastOrDefault` return `null` by default. You can see the documentation about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb301849.aspx). So you can try to catch the exeption to see that.

Comment: it **does** work without `@item.UserName`
VS stops recognize `GetRolesForUser()`
after I`m writing `(@item.UserName)` inside it

Comment: Have you override GetRolesForUser() ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all but I assume your method `Roles.GetRolesForUser()` return `IEnumerable`. For using linq extensions write like as:

```
@Roles.GetRolesForUser().LastOrDefault(r=> r.UserName == item.UserName)
```